# как сделать свой тип в c++?

Tags: c++, c

Например я могу сделать в структуре или в классе вот так.

```
unsigned int ax:16;
```

Мне надо сделать al и ah, каждый по одному байту и ещё чтобы они были указателями. Такое вроде нельзя сделать, но всё же хочу уточнить. И ещё чтобы al и ah указывали на нужное смещение в ax.

Comment: [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) + [bit fields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/bit_field). [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3065948/5045688)

Comment: Вы слишком много хотите. Указатель не может указывать на битовое поле. Откуда взялись все эти странные требования?

Comment: Ant хотел узнать можно ли так.

Answer (score 0):

Создавать с помощью `union` нежелательно, так как компилятор может с оптимизировать и убрать весь код, который не нужен. Структура битовых полей тоже не очень удобна, так как адрес будет не доступен. Компилятор может создать реализацию на свой вкус. Проще сделать как делают все сишники:

```
# include<iostream>
class R{
public :
uint64_t volatile & rx(){return *(uint64_t volatile *)r;}
uint32_t volatile & ex(){return *(uint32_t volatile *)r;}
uint16_t volatile & x(){return *(uint16_t volatile *)r;}
uint8_t volatile & h(){return *(uint8_t volatile *)(r+1);}
uint8_t volatile & l(){return *(uint8_t volatile *)r;}
private:
volatile uint8_t r[8];
};

int main(){
    R r;
    r.l()=1;
    r.h()=1;
  std::cout<<"r.x="<<r.x()<<"\n"; }
```

итого:

```
$ ./a.out 
r.x=257
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что тут нарушается strict aliasing.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `volatile` - спасёт ?

Comment: [Тут пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2981867/2752075), что не спасает. Я бы сделал геттеры и сеттеры через [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy#Notes).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я нашёл только, чтоб не забывали ставить `volatile` везде. Подправлю, должно быть люкс.

Comment: Лучше бы наоборот, хранить переменную uint64_t, а обращаться к составляющим байтам по указателям (char*). В этом случае проблемы strict aliasing нет, а видимый эффект тот же.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Если постоянно в коде используется ссылка на **x**, то компилятор может у себя хранить содержимое в **ax** постоянно. И вдруг программа поменяла байт **l**, и кеш в **ax** уже неликвид. Помогает только **volatile** или **memcpy**.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужны указатели, то например, так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void
setalah (uint16_t *p, uint8_t **ppl, uint8_t **pph)
{
  uint8_t *pp = (uint8_t *)p;
  int v = 1;
  char *low = (char *)&v;

  if (*low) {  // dynamic check endianness (low or big-endian system)
    // well, may be better to do as #ifdef ??? It's your choice
    *ppl = pp;
    *pph = pp + 1;
  } else {
    *pph = pp;
    *ppl = pp + 1;
  }
}

#define ah (*pah)
#define al (*pal)

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  // *****  вот этот фрагмент -- ответ на вопрос
  uint16_t a;
  uint8_t *pal, *pah;

  setalah(&a, &pal, &pah);
  // ***** конец фрагмента


  printf("&a: %p  pal: %p pah: %p\n",
     (void *)(&a), pal, pah);

  int v;
  while (scanf("%d", &v) == 1) {
    a = v;
    int vl = *pal, vh = *pah;
    printf("v: 0x%02x vl: 0x%02x vh: 0x%02x\n", v, vl, vh);
    printf("ah: %d al: %d\n", ah, al);
  }
}
```

А для доступа к памяти по указателю, как к переменной (по имени) всегда можно написать простые `#define`.

---

P.S.
gnu компилятор не сомневается, что это программа на С++